# Calling dotnet From JNA

Tags: .net, jna

When I try to run my code I get

```
public class Main {
     public interface RnowUtilUnitTest extends Library {
         RnowUtilUnitTest INSTANCE = (RnowUtilUnitTest) Native.loadLibrary("D://RightNowCRMHelper.dll", 
            RnowUtilUnitTest.class); 
         void Test_GetValueFornamedID();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        RnowUtilUnitTest sdll = RnowUtilUnitTest.INSTANCE;
        sdll.Test_GetValueFornamedID();
        //sdll.Test_ExecuteQuery();
    }
}
```

I get the following error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'Test_GetValueFornamedID': The specified procedure could not be found.

```
at com.sun.jna.Function.<init>(Function.java:179)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:344)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:324)
at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:203)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.Test_GetValueFornamedID(Unknown Source)
at test.Main.main(Main.java:34)
```

Here is my dot net code

```
[TestMethod]
  61         public void Test_GetValueFornamedID()
  62         {
  63             objRnowUtil = new RnowUtil("Test");
  64 
  65             //Invoke the GetValuesForNamedID operation, supplying the appropriate string value
  66             NamedID[] valuesForNamedID = objRnowUtil.GetValueFornamedID(null, "Incident.CustomFields.c.query_status");
  67 
  68             Assert.IsNotNull(valuesForNamedID);
  69             Assert.IsTrue(valuesForNamedID.Length > 0);
  70             foreach (NamedID namedID in valuesForNamedID)
  71             {
  72                 if (namedID.Name.ToLower() == "Repeat Call".ToLower())
  73                 {
  74                     Assert.AreEqual(2383, namedID.ID.id);
  75                 }
  76 
  77 
  78             }
  79 
  80         }
  81
```

Comment: From what i read about JNA it is made to call native code, a .net DLL is not a regular DLL (it's not native code and requires the CLR to run it). Odds are the answer is "you can't do that" with a more complex answer being "you can do that if you provide a native dll which itself self hosts the .net runtime and passes methods calls down to the .net version" but that's a lot harder than it seems

Comment: I would be very surprised if this was possible.   .NET Dll's are not native code and require the .net runtime to execute.